# Disactivating RouterLinkActive attribute conditionally to some value

Tags: angular, typescript

In this simple menu item component:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'nav-item',
  template: `
    <a [routerLink]="routeUrl" 
    routerLinkActive="active-link" 
    >
    </a>
  `
})

export class NavItemComponent {
  @Input() routerLinkActiveIsDisabled: boolean;
}
```

I would like `routerLinkActive` to be used on only certain items not all.

How can I make it so that the `routerLinkActive` attribute is removed  if `routerLinkActiveIsDisabled` is `true`

Answer (score 6):

Below template code will add the attribute `routerLinkActive` to it's corresponding tag only if the value of `routerLinkActiveIsDisabled` is set to false (*non-truthy value*).

```
[attr.routerLinkActive]="routerLinkActiveIsDisabled ? null: active-link"
```

or

```
[attr.routerLinkActive]="routerLinkActiveIsDisabled ? null: 'active-link'"
```

Comment: Great stuff! impressed :) +1

Comment: active-link is highlighted with this error : the property "link" that you are trying to access doesn't exist in class declaration

Comment: pls remove `routerLinkActive="active-link"` this attribute from the tag. And give a try to the second option..

Comment: Pls post the corresponding tag.. If possible, pls create a plnkr

Comment: @Lev still it's not?

Answer (score 0):

u can use

```
<a [routerLink]="routeUrl" 
[routerLinkActive]="{{classname if link is active}}" 
>
</a>
```

or use *ngIf and have two different "a" tags

```
<a *ngIf="!routerLinkActiveIsDisabled"
[routerLink]="routeUrl" 
routerLinkActive="active-link" 
>
</a>

<a *ngIf="routerLinkActiveIsDisabled"
[routerLink]="routeUrl" 
>
</a>
```